# Docusign Anchor Tags Data population scope live vs Sandbox

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have a weird problem with docusign (C# nuget DocusSign.eSign.dll v.2.0.0)

I have:

- 1 envelope
- 1 recipient
- 2 documents (identical templates little differences in content)

  - per document:

    - 1 SignHereTabs,
    - 2 TextTabs located with AnchorString (on envelope will be 2 signhere, 4 texttabs)

On demo.docusign.net everything works good. 
On live (na2), initially I believed is something related to text tab shared attribute, isn't that.

It seems that document2 text tabs are rendered on document1 text tabs, (checked using different text tabs names, last name is on both docs).

Here is how envelope definition looks like (removed some of the values)

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "Agreement 1",
      "fileExtension": "docx",
      "documentBase64": " removed base64 document"
    },
    {
      "documentId": "2",
      "name": "Agreement 2",
      "fileExtension": "docx",
      "documentBase64": " removed base64 document"
    }
  ],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "anchorString": "Signature: _________",
              "anchorXOffset": "60",
              "anchorYOffset": "8"
            },
            {
              "documentId": "2",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "anchorString": "Signature: _________",
              "anchorXOffset": "60",
              "anchorYOffset": "8"
            }
          ],
          "textTabs": [
            {
              "shared": "false",
              "name": "Printed Name",
              "tabLabel": "Insert Printed Name",
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "anchorString": "Printed Name: _________ ",
              "anchorXOffset": "80",
              "anchorYOffset": "-5"
            },
            {
              "shared": "false",
              "name": "Title",
              "tabLabel": "InsertTitle",
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "anchorString": "Title: _________ ",
              "anchorXOffset": "60",
              "anchorYOffset": "-5"
            },
            {
              "shared": "false",
              "name": "Printed Name",
              "tabLabel": "Insert Printed Name",
              "documentId": "2",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "anchorString": "Printed Name: _________ ",
              "anchorXOffset": "80",
              "anchorYOffset": "-5"
            },
            {
              "shared": "false",
              "name": "Title",
              "tabLabel": "InsertTitle",
              "documentId": "2",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "anchorString": "Title: _________  ",
              "anchorXOffset": "60",
              "anchorYOffset": "-5"
            }
          ]
        },
        "name": "Test test",
        "email": "testemail@test-company.com",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "clientUserId": "c82db255-7df6-4b03-9d71-51b1b2ad8f6e"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emailSubject": "Some agreement"
}
```

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Docusign [Anchor Tags](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs#tab-positioning) feature.

> When the DocuSign Service receives a request that contains tabs with anchor information, it searches the document for instances of the anchorString property. When found, it places a tab of the specified type for the designated recipient

See more information [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeTabs/#anchoring-tabs)

For your case the **documentId** for a tab is irrelevant as you are specifying an anchorString.

You can simplify your request by removing the following from your tab definition

- Duplicate tabs
- DocumentId. The tab will be applied wherever the string specified in **anchorString** property is found.

*Sample request*

```
  {
   "documents": [--Documents Array Removed],
   "recipients": {
     "signers": [
       {
         "tabs": {
           "signHereTabs": [
             {
               "anchorString": "Signature: _________",
               "anchorXOffset": "60",
               "anchorYOffset": "8"
             }
           ],
           "textTabs": [
             {
               "shared": "false",
               "name": "Printed Name",
               "tabLabel": "Insert Printed Name",
               "anchorString": "Printed Name: _________ ",
               "anchorXOffset": "80",
               "anchorYOffset": "-5"
             },
             {
               "shared": "false",
               "name": "Title",
               "tabLabel": "InsertTitle",
               "anchorString": "Title: _________ ",
               "anchorXOffset": "60",
               "anchorYOffset": "-5"
             }
           ]
         },
         "name": "Test test",
         "email": "testemail@test-company.com",
         "recipientId": "1",
         "clientUserId": "c82db255-7df6-4b03-9d71-51b1b2ad8f6e"
       }
     ]
   },
   "emailSubject": "Some agreement"
 }
```

Comment: Yes you are right, still there is a difference between sandbox and live, I opened a case and found out from ducusign support team that there is a setting data population scope (anchor search scope), in doucsign demo is the document in live is the envelope, I will return with updates when I will have some.

Comment: @SilentTremor Please let me know when you have an update. I have tried with the request I have posted in the answer in both Sandbox & live (prod). I am seeing the same behavior in both the environments. The tabs are placed on all the documents based on the AnchorString. Have you tried with the JSON I have provided?

Comment: @CodingDwag, it seems timezones are a problem, I thing tomorrow morning PST someone from docusign will take care of my request, meanwhile, I'll try to find a solution from code. You were right, I was duplicating the tabs,  but on sandbox Data Population Scope = document on live is Data Population Scope= envelope, in prod this cause field value to be shared, beside waiting for docusign engineers to change my setting I'm want to find solution in my code   https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/autoplace

Comment: @CodingDwag, indeed my problem was with "Automatically replicate information in fields with the same Data Label" set "on an individual document", thx again for showing me wrong text tabs declaration.

Comment: @SilentTremor Please update your question with additional details you have discovered so that others can benefit.